# How to Change Date in Application in android?

Tags: android

I want to write Text View today's date so changed today and the date for the next day?

Comment: can you explain your answer with some code. please use English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to set a TextView so that it will always display the current date, you can do it like this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1; //we add one because the months actually start at 0
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.your_text_view);
String newText = "Today's Date: "+month+"."+day+"."+year;
textView.setText(newText);
```